# Does there exist $B$ for which $BB^T=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

My question is

> Does there exist a real matrix $B_{n\times m}$ with $m<n$ for which $BB^T=I_n$?

Why do I need this?

> Suppose we are given a real matrix $Q_{m\times n}$ (again, with $m<n$) and we want to show that $\det(QQ^T)\geq 0$. If we find such a $B_{n\times m}$ for which  $BB^T=I_n$, then define
>   $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 
>   Q_{m\times n}     & 0\\ 
>   0 & B_{n \times m} 
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   So
>   $$\begin{align}\det(AA^T) 
> &= \det\begin{pmatrix} 
>   QQ^T     & 0\\ 
>   0 & BB^T
> \end{pmatrix}_{(m+n)\times(m+n)} \\
>  &= \det\begin{pmatrix} 
>   QQ^T     & 0\\ 
>   0 & I_n
> \end{pmatrix}_{(m+n)\times(m+n)} \\
> &=\det(QQ^T).
> \end{align}$$
>   Now, $A$ is a square matrix which means its determinant is non-negative, Q.E.D.

I tried to find an example, but couldn't. I just don't know how to start.

Comment: No, because $\text{rank}\left(XY\right)\leq \min\left(\text{rank}(X), \text{rank}(Y)\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Git Gud  said, such $B$ cannot exist.

The natural way (to me) to do this is the following. For $x\in \mathbb C^n$ a unit eigenvector for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $QQ^T$, we have (noting that since $Q$ is real, $Q^T=Q^*$)
$$
\lambda=\lambda x^*x=x^*(\lambda x)=x^*QQ^*x=(Q^*x)^*Q^*x\geq0.
$$
So all eigenvalues of $QQ^T=QQ^*$ are non-negative, which implies that $\det QQ^T\geq0$.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! That was really nice. However, you need to do some editions as Git Gud said.

Comment: @GitGud: indeed. Edited, thanks.